# WindowStyle = "None" + ResizeMode = "NoResize" = problem

Tags: wpf, window, styles

problem is when i set my windowstyle to none and change resizemode to no resize, and run it, the height and width is bigger at runtime

Comment: i wanna know whats causing it to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you've either set the height and width of the window to be larger than the window would automatically size to adjust to its contents. Or done the opposite.

**EDIT**

Ok, so considering the new information in the comments below:

The reason why the button's position has changed is because you've explicitly set the `Margin` of the `Button` to be 203 units left and 209 units down from the top left point of the containing panel (I.E. your grid; Which is why it appears where it does.

I'm unsure why the preview is incorrect in this case.

Comment: http://i56.tinypic.com/2hx64va.jpg kindly see the screenshot regarding my problem, the one inside that blue background was the output when i run it

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your problem is. Is it that one of the buttons positions has changed from the preview?

Comment: yeah, the position seems to be wrong in runtime, just wondering why does it happen

Answer (score 0):

In my case the XAML tag of the Window had the Property SizeToContent="True" and all I had to do was to remove it.